# Facing x509: certificate signed by unknown authority errVerbose=x509: certificate signed by unknown authority issuer while running the chainlink node

Tags: docker, x509certificate, ubuntu-20.04, chainlink

Running the chainlink node using docker on WSL2 ubuntu 20.04, set all the parameters, tried with both goerli and sepolia wss as well as https clients.

*[ERROR] Failed to redial RPC node; still unreachable: error while dialing websocket: wss://goerli.infura.io/ws/v3/4f1d3ea7b23644dda6a766f1d42471a5: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority client/node_lifecycle.go:369     err=error while
dialing websocket: wss://goerli.infura.io/ws/v3/4f1d3ea7b23644dda6a766f1d42471a5: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority errVerbose=x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
error while dialing websocket: wss://goerli.infura.io/ws/v3/4f1d3ea7b23644dda6a766f1d42471a5
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/chains/evm/client.(*node).dial
/chainlink/core/chains/evm/client/node.go:263
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/chains/evm/client.(*node).unreachableLoop
/chainlink/core/chains/evm/client/node_lifecycle.go:367
runtime.goexit
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1594 evmChainID=11155111 logger=1.11.0@150ec84.EVM.Node.Lifecycle.Unreachable node=(primary)primary-0-11155111:wss://goerli.infura.io/ws/v3/4f1d3ea7b23644dda6a766f1d42471a5 nodeName=primary-0-11155111 nodeState=Unreachable nodeTier=primary stacktrace=github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/chains/evm/client.(*node).unreachableLoop
/chainlink/core/chains/evm/client/node_lifecycle.go:369*

Comment: It looks that your docker does not have a CA certificate installed. Can you try to install the ca-certificates package for your Linux distribution?

Comment: HI frank, thanks for the response. But I installed all the ca-certificates. I could able to pull the images from internet with docker pull. But the websocker or https connections from inside docker containers is not happening. Any idea?

Comment: I don't have a WSL environment and I set up Chainlink node in docker under MacOS, and I did not get into this problem. Can you try to CURL Goerli and Sepolia RPC? I don't think CA is one of configs you need to define specifically for Chainlink.